# Calling 3rd party API asp .net Core

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I am quite new to ASP .Net. I don't have very much experience. For one project i want to access the Spotify web API. I have been able to connect to the api and make calls. But now i have to make it with the correct architecture. Previously i have already created a app that could access a database with the "repository pattern". So i decided that i wanted to access the api in a similar way. I have already made a few classes with which i am able to access the api. But i don't know how too continue.

here's an example of a class + interface i've created:

```
namespace SpotifyGen.ApiWrapper
{
    public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
    {
        HttpClient _client;

        public UserRepository(HttpClient client)
        {
            _client = client; 
        }

        public async Task<UserDTO> GetUser()
        {
            return await ApiContext.Get<UserDTO>(_client, "/v1/me");
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace SpotifyGen.ApiWrapper.interfaces
{
    public interface IUserRepository
    {
        public Task<UserDTO> GetUser();
    }
}
```

I have created two more similar classes and interfaces.

I also created my own "context" class. With this class i can access the api by just supplying an object type(T), an url and for the "Post" method httpcontent.

```
namespace SpotifyGen.Logic
{
    public static class ApiContext
    {
        public static async Task<T> Get<T>(HttpClient client, string requesturi)
        {
            using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(requesturi);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var model = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
                return model;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }

        public static async Task<T> Post<T>(HttpClient client, string requesturi, HttpContent content)
        {
            using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(requesturi, content);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var model = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
                return model;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is how would i structure my apiwrapper layer(classlibrary)? and because i also need to use dependency injection how would i do this. For example i know it is possible to supply a class with a httpclient, but i cant get it to work.Also is it smart that i structured my files like this? And i'm currently stuck on how i would continue.
[My file structure for the "apiwrapper" layer(classlibrary)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UflV4.png)

I would greatly appreciate if any one could point me in the right direction - perhaps to some sample code or a usefull tutorial.

Comment: I am not 100% clear on what you are asking, to me it seems a bit broad. Clean architecture would suggest your interfaces sit in the Domain layer and your implementations in your 'Api Wrapper' layer, thus inverting control. You typically want to avoid domain taking on any dependencies. Could you provide a bit more info or clarify exactly what part you would like to alter/clean up?

Comment: Also I dont believe you can inject a concrete class into your Repository, it needs to be an interface so in you case, try injecting `IHttpClient`

Comment: I guess what i wanted to ask is now that i have all the repositories. What would be the best way to access/use them. Do i need to make a class in which i put all the repositories, and create all of them at once. Or have them separate and and create them each one at a time.

Comment: I would typically go about keeping each domain object separate and create a service which would handle the business logic. Ill add an answer explaining this.

Comment: Okay, so i would put the repositories and irepositories in the domain layer. So then put the apicontext class in the apiwrapper layer right?

Comment: Nope, give me one sec, prepping the answer, almost done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1 Dependency Injection

In order to make use of dependency injection you want to inject an interface and not an implementation. Replace `HttpClient` with `IHttpClient` and your wrapper would like so.

```
namespace SpotifyGen.ApiWrapper
{
    public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
    {
        IHttpClient _client;

        public UserRepository(IHttpClient client)
        {
            _client = client; 
        }

        public async Task<UserDTO> GetUser()
        {
            return await ApiContext.Get<UserDTO>(_client, "/v1/me");
        }
    }
}
```

#### 2 Inversion  of control

There are several ways of doing this but to the best of my knowledge a clean architecture would ensure your **repository interfaces** sit within your domain layer. Move your repository interfaces into the Domain layer and leave the **repository implementations** in their own seperate project.

This ultimately means your domain wont have any dependencies on the various implementations you choose, thus allowing you to swap out contexts etc without affecting the domain layer.

#### 3 Domain layer

In your domain layer I would create a service per repository that would handle the business logic required. Imagine:

```
IArtistService
IPlayerService
ITokenService
```

The implementations for these would reside in the Domain layer and you would inject the relevant repositories.

#### Dependency graph

```
SpotifyGen.ApiWrapper depends on -->> Domain
Data depends on -->> Domain
```

I don't have time to create a UML diagram.

There is a book called Clean Architecture, its old but definitely worth a read. Id also suggest reading clean code prior to this if you haven't already

**[Edit]**
To answer part of your question I missed.

Your api context could sit within your Wrapper project or you could specify the interface in the Wrapper project and add yet another layer of abstraction. Going this far does depend on whether you plan on swapping that low level component out in the future or not.

In my opinion I would place it behind an interface at least to allow it to be injected where necessary and thus replaceable.

I am sure others will have varied opinions on this.

Comment: Thank you so much, when i'm done with building the application from your advice would you be willing to check if i did it right?

Comment: Sure, we can work through various bits ;) if the answer helped feel free to accept it

Comment: Just a small technical detail: There is no actual requirement preventing other types than interfaces to be used for injection, it's just seen as good and standard practice as it follows good decoupling principles. One .NET Core-related example of something  not actually registered as an interface is the HttpClient in the example above, due to the underlying socket issues that pose some risk ofdestabilizing one's app. Prefer using either IHttpClientFactory or a typed client with HttpClient (see: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Thanks @Classe great to know

Comment: @Tak90 i created a uml-diagram from your explanation. Is this right? [link](https://imgur.com/a/1R1QCGd)

Comment: I think you have got the gist of it. The client code that will use `IUserService` and potentially `IuserRepository` knows nothing of the implementation and you have kept your domain clean of dependencies.

Comment: Great!! thank you so much. I do have another question though. To access the Spotify web api do need to get a access token. I just created a "TokenRepository" to do this. Is this smart? because the httpclients need to have this token as a authentication header.

Comment: There are several questions to be answered here, but we typically get a token only when required as its quite an expensive operation. I am not sure you need a whole repo just to get the token, as I would think its just another api call. I have seen on some projects the token is cached and used for a given time but as soon as you get into caching things might get tricky.

Comment: To be a bit more concrete, if you intend on having several clients that all need to execute the same token request code, then having a service that does just that is fine. If its just that client that is ever going to use it then Id keep it on the client as it should be a simple method to get the token. I understand this isnt the most helpful answer, but without knowing all the details its difficult to advise.

Comment: Also if you plan on following some sort of standard, then Id avoid calling it a repository. Naming is really up for debate, but classes that do CRUD ops would be called repositories, anything with business logic, would be a service. In this case your class is neither.

Comment: okay, [here's a guide ] (https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/) on how the authorization works. What i thought i could do is create the token in startup and whenever i inject the ihttpclient it would already have the token as a authorization header.

Comment: It seems as though you want a singleton registered that will just hand out the token. Does each user need a different token?

Comment: yes, whenever you log in with your spotify credentials a token is created which contain data including your account info.

Comment: In that case you dont want to create the token on startup, since the app will startup only once and your users will login after. Each user when they login will require you to make a call to their api and retrieve a token. Id say you need to avoid a singleton in this case and perhaps give a bit of thought into how you intend to use the token

Comment: All i am using the token for is for the authentication header in the httpclient.

Comment: How i did it previously is that whenever  you navigated to a certain controller you would be redirected to a url where you could log in with your spotify account. And after you would be redirected back to the controller with a code. With this code i would generate the token.

Comment: Chiming in again: From what I can guess, you're looking for an OAuth2 bearer-token for the API-authentication. Do note that such token will come with an expiration time, meaning it will have to be requested again if the app is to live more than an hour.  OAuth2 is quite standard, so there should be plenty of examples out there. I prefer keeping token handling within what service I use to perform the API calls for external API Clients. I extracted and commented a gist that might be a helpful starting point: https://gist.github.com/Loevgren/58fe4b79bdf407991b5428d74dfa742e

Comment: Thank you, thats very userfull. I don't really have to worry about the expiration time of the token in my application. I have been struggling with the dependency injection of the IHttpClient/IHttpClientFactory in my classes. Would you be willing to show me an example of how that would work in the UML-diagram that i made [link](https://imgur.com/a/1R1QCGd).

Comment: Could you drop us some example code so we can see exactly what you are struggling with?

Comment: The (AspNetCore.App) default Microsft.Extensions.Http-lib provides a handy little extension method on ServiceCollection called AddHttpClient that will register everything you need for it to be injected, resulting in that all you should have to do for it to get injected is to add services.AddHttpClient() to Startup.ConfigureServices (Startup.cs).